# CreateJS MovieClip performance issue

Tags: createjs, adobe-animate

I'm using Adobe Animate HTML5 to create a board game to run on Smart TV (low-performance machine).

All my previous games were done using AS3.
I quickly found there is no way to create a Sprite anymore (A movie clips with only 1 frame).
After creating my board game (no code yet just elements) which is basically movie clips inside other movie clips. All single frame.

I checked the FPS on LG TV and so it is done from 60 to 20. On a static image.
After research, I found that is the **advance** method in **MovieClip** class there is a constant check to update the frame.
I added a change to check if the MovieClip class total frame is equal to 1 to change it the mode of the MovieClip to a single frame. This increases performance back to 60 FPS.

Who do I go to, to check and maybe fix/"add a feature" to the code of createjs

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

code issues or suggestions can be logged here https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/issues for CreateJS.  All the best.

Answer (score 0):

inside html-code in script part there is a line

```
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
```

Remove it and call the update manually when you need it (when something has changed)

```
stage.update();
```

Comment: i need the "tick", i don't want manual update, i want a single frame MovieClip.

Comment: then just instead 
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
write
stage.update();